# how to set cache path selenium webdriver firefox c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need the cache has been preserved and it was possible to reconnect.Tried this :

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"D:\сacheFirefox",false);
 IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
 MessageBox.Show(profile.ProfileDirectory);
```

but the folder `D:\сacheFirefox` empty, but the `MessageBox` displays the path in temp folder, but he doesn't exist Can you help ?

Comment: Might be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685755/retaining-cache-in-firefox-and-chrome-browser-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Dhru'soni nope, i need save all new session at another path