# how do you do text only mode in selenium chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want my browser to look like this

[image]

only text no image at all

i tried

```
options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
```

it only disabled images but not disabled ui on the site

any help??

Comment: Did you try these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240886/disable-css-and-image-in-selenium-chromedriver-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031428/how-to-disable-css-in-python-selenium-using-chromeoptions

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

or you can use the chrome extension 'Block Image' from extension downloader. This link will be helpful for you
[Disable images in Selenium Google ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657976/disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver)

Comment: it only disables image i was meaning i want to disable site ui too

Comment: Do you check with disabling JS as well

Comment: Yes i tried disabling everything

Comment: Ok you should add this line after opening page
`driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector("head").remove();""")`
It will remove the header of the page which contains all the JS and CSS

Comment: I tried and its working.

Comment: Oki i will try this